# Populating new field in QGIS only if row and column names match

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, field-calculator

Is there a way in QGIS or with pyqgis to populate a new column only when row and column names match (like in the example below)?

It's easy to do that with R but I can't find a solution in QGIS or with PyQGIS.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution without PyQGIS or Python

Use the following epression `if(array_contains(array('test2', 'test3', 'test8'), "test"), attribute($currentfeature, "test"), NULL)` in the *"Expression Dialog"*

[image: result]

*Note:* Beforehand you will need to create an array that will contain all the attributes' names, e.g. `array('attribute1', 'attribute2', ...)`, i.e. `array('Polygon1', 'Polygon2', 'Polygon3', 'Polygon4')`.

So, your final expression may be looking like `if(array_contains(array('Polygon1', 'Polygon2', 'Polygon3', 'Polygon4'), "ID"), attribute($currentfeature, "ID"), NULL)`.

Comment: Thanks Taras, I have never used the array functions yet but I will have a look at the method you posted ! I'll keep you updated ! :)

Comment: I don't understand how I should create an array of all my attributes names first... In the example you provided, I don't see where you did that ?
Could you possibly add some details to your anwser please ? Many thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: It was done here `array('test2', 'test3', 'test8')`, so you simply do `array('Polygon1', 'Polygon2', 'Polygon3', 'Polygon4')`

Comment: Aaaah I thought that I had to create the array somewhere first before using the expression ! Sorry for the silly question and thank you so much for your help Taras !

Comment: There are no silly questions! Always welcome! And instead of `"test"` use yours `"ID"`.